# difference between catch (domain_error const & x) and catch (const domain_error & x)

Tags: c++, exception, reference, constants

I would like to know whether the following statements are same or different

```
1> catch (domain_error const & x) 
2> catch (const domain_error & x)
3> catch (domain_error & const x) // I think this is illegal
```

Basically, I thought case 1> and case 2> are same and case 3> is not legal syntax.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct; the first two are equivalent and the last one is an error.

More generally, when dealing with references, the syntaxes

```
const T&
```

and

```
T const &
```

are equivalent, while

```
T & const
```

is not allowed.

Comment: An explanation is provided [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.6)

Answer (score 2):

**1)** and **2)** are the same, whereas **3)** is invalid as you can't modify the reference itself -- you can only modify what it refers to.

Here are the rules:

In C `const` was put before the type to make it constant. This is also supported in C++, but there's a new, extended syntax added: `const` may also be put to the right of the type to make constant what's to the left of it. Examples:

- `const char * c;` - this defines a non-constant pointer to constant char c. That is, you can modify the value of the pointer, but not the value it points at. This is a C syntex.
- `char const * c;` - same, but using C++ `const` rules.
- `char * const p;` - this defines a constant pointer to a non-constant char. You can't modify the pointer itself, but can modify the value pointed.
- `char const * const p;` - this defines a constant pointer to a constant char. You can't modify anything here.
- `char const * * const p;` - this defines a constant pointer to a non-constant pointer to a constant char. How cool is that?

Comment: can you give an example of usage for the last item?